# Adding Table View Cell not working in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I am trying to create a shopping list app. I am very new to Objective-C. Somehow this block of code is not working and I don't know what I did wrong. Whenever I type something in the textfield and click add, the text is not added to the table view.

HEADER FILE:

```
@interface NotesViewController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *notes;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *noteTitleText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *noteBlockTableView;

@end
```

IMPLEMENTATION FILE:

```
@implementation NotesViewController

@synthesize notes; @synthesize noteTitleText; @synthesize noteBlockTableView;

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [notes count]; }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *tableViewTitle;
    tableViewTitle = [notes objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:nil];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[tableViewTitle objectForKey:@"cellTitle"]];
    return cell;

}

-(IBAction)addNote {

    NSDictionary *tableViewTitle;
    tableViewTitle = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[noteTitleText text], @"cellTitle", nil];
    [notes addObject:tableViewTitle];
    [noteBlockTableView reloadData];
    noteTitleText.text = @"";
}
```

Comment: Do you initialise `notes` (to an empty mutable array) somewhere (in `init` or `viewDidLoad`, usually)?

Comment: Also, in modern Objective-C, you don't need to synthesize properties, that's done automatically, and you probably want to use dictionary literals (`@{@"cellTitle": noteTitleText.text}`) and accessors (`tableViewTitle[@"cellTitle"]`). Even better, you should use a new class for this rather than a dictionary.

Comment: And you shouldn't allocate `UITableViewCell`s, you should use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should override `numberOfSectionsInTableView` function and `return 1`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Objective-C!

Before using `NSMutableArray`, you should initialize it first, like this:

```
# NotesViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    notes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

[It should work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f8yn.png)

Answer (score 0):

First initialise the array notes, then you should allocate cell like this in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSDictionary *tableViewTitle;
tableViewTitle = [notes objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.textLabel.text = [tableViewTitle objectForKey:@"cellTitle"];

return cell;

 }
```